# How can I make Django Query Return Nothing When Subquery Is Empty

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have Django query with sub-query like this

```
cust_order = TOrder.objects \
        .select_related('user') \
        .annotate(category_name=Subquery(TOrderDetail.objects
                                        .filter(t_order=OuterRef('id'),
                                                deleted_at__isnull=True,
                                                deleted_by__isnull=True)
                                        .values_list('product__product_category__name', flat=True)[:1])
                   cust_feedback=Subquery(TOrderFeedback.objects
                                                 .filter(t_order=OuterRef('id'),
                                                         deleted_at__isnull=True,
                                                         deleted_by__isnull=True,
                                                 .values_list('message', flat=True)[:1]),
```

The problem is, some times the sub-query of cust_feedback will empty, and how can I do filter if the cust_feedback is empty then the parent query should return nothing ?

Thanks